# opentok videocall and payment intergartion does not working in same window?

Tags: paypal, payment, opentok

I am working on `opentok` video call and set time limit for call.
I am looking for functionality where User, before call disconnects the user can pay(Using paypal) and continue call.

How I can get payment response from `paypal` in other window to `opentok` calling window without disconnect to session...

Comment: This is `OPENTOK` API Specific question, please paste some code so that we can identify the possibility..

Comment: what is the platform you are using? Is it the web application?